# Limit of an integral of a sequence of functions.

Tags: analysis

We have the following problem. I know that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{X}(f_{n}(x) - f(x))^{2}dx = \infty,$$
where $f_{n},f : X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are functions for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, i want to prove that there exists $x\in X$ such that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(f_{n}(x) - f(x))^{2} = \infty$$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim, as stated, is false. Take $X = \Bbb R$, $f_n (x) = 0$ for every $n$ and every $x$, and $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$. Note that the limit you're asking about is $1$, not $\infty.$

By the way, I didn't just give this example to be a jerk. I'm *guessing* that there's some additional hypothesis that you forgot to mention. And if you forgot to mention it, this example will show you why it's necessary, and perhaps help guide you to finding your own proof of the complete conjecture, rather than trying to prove this false sub-conjecture.

Comment: Yes, i forgot to say that $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with finite meause.